# How to split/crop a pdf along the middle using pyPdf

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a pdf that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrfI2.jpg) and i'd like to crop all the text out, almost right down the middle of the page. I found this script that does something simmilar:

```
def splitHorizontal():
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input1 = PdfFileReader(file("in.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()

numPages = input1.getNumPages()
print "document has %s pages." % numPages

for i in range(numPages):
    page = input1.getPage(i)
    print page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y()
    page.trimBox.lowerLeft = (25, 25)
    page.trimBox.upperRight = (225, 225)
    page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (50, 50)
    page.cropBox.upperRight = (200, 200)
    output.addPage(page)

outputStream = file("out.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

However these crop dimensions are tuned to that specific example.
Can anyone show me how to find the correct crop dimensions.

Comment: What does `getUpperLeft_x()` give you?

Answer (score 2):

I originally got the script from here --> [Cropping pages of a .pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457207/cropping-pages-of-a-pdf-file).

I read more into what the author had said, finally realizing that he had said:

> The resulting document has a trim box that is 200x200 points and starts at 25,25 points inside the media box. The crop box is 25 points inside the trim box.

meaning

```
page.cropBox.upperRight = (200, 200)
```

must control the ultimate margins, i therefore adjusted the statement to

```
page.cropBox.upperLeft = (290, 792)
```

To mirror the cropping onto the other side and make sure the cropping holds the full vertical value

Answer (score 0):

Chops each page in half, e.g. if a source were
created in booklet form, and then re-combines it
for further processing eg. text extraction

Importing required libraries

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter,PdfFileReader,PdfFileMerger
```

Splitting Left Part

```
with open("docu.pdf", "rb") as in_f:
    input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    numPages = input1.getNumPages()

    for i in range(numPages):
        page = input1.getPage(i)
        page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (60, 50)
        page.cropBox.upperRight = (305, 700)
        output.addPage(page)

    with open("left.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
        output.write(out_f)
```

Splitting right part :

```
with open("docu.pdf", "rb") as in_f:
    input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    numPages = input1.getNumPages()

    for i in range(numPages):
        page = input1.getPage(i)
        page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (300, 50)
        page.cropBox.upperRight = (540, 700)
        output.addPage(page)

    with open("right.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
        output.write(out_f)
```

Combining left with right (two columns to two pages)

```
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("left.pdf","rb"))
input2 = PdfFileReader(open("right.pdf","rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
numPages = input1.getNumPages()

for i in range(numPages):
    l = input1.getPage(i)
    output.addPage(l)
    r = input2.getPage(i)
    output.addPage(r)

with open("out.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
    output.write(out_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge and I wrote this (require PyPDF2):

https://gist.github.com/kintaro1981/eb6cfc6f40a7fb39744f5ae630d58fd5

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This script splits each pdf page in half vertically and merge them in a single PDF in order.
It asks how many pages do you want to skip to avoid splitting a book cover or a specific number of initial pages.
Usage:
python cutpdfpages.py <filename.pdf> <newfilename.pdf>
"""

import sys
import copy
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

file = str(sys.argv[1])
newfile = str(sys.argv[2])

with open(file, "rb") as pdf1:
    pdf = PdfReader(pdf1)
    output = PdfWriter()
    numpages = pdf.getNumPages()
    page2skip =  int(input('Insert how many pages do you want to skip: '))

    for i in range(page2skip, numpages):
        page = pdf.pages[i]
        pagebis = copy.copy(page)
        page.mediabox.upper_left = (page.mediabox.right / 2, page.mediabox.top,)
        output.add_page(page)
        pagebis.mediabox.upper_right = (pagebis.mediabox.right / 2, pagebis.mediabox.top,)
        output.add_page(pagebis)

    with open(newfile, "wb") as newpdf:
        output.write(newpdf)
```