# Unable to use pypdf module

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I have installed the pyPdf module successfully using the command pip install pydf but when I use the module using the import command I get the following error:

```
enC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\__init__.py in <module>()
1 from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
  2 __all__ = ["pdf"]
ImportError: No module named 'pdf'
```

What should I do? I have installed the pdf module as well but still the error does not go away.

Answer (score 33):

This is a problem of an old version of `pypdf`. The [history of pypdf](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/history.html) is a bit compliated, but the gist of it:

> Use `pypdf>=3.1.0`. All lowercase, no number. Since December 2022, it's the best supported version.

**Install pypdf**

```
$ sudo -H pip install pypdf
```

You might need to replace `pip` by `pip2` or `pip3` if you use Python 2 or Python 3.

**Use pypdf**

```
import pypdf
```

## WARNING: PyPDF3 and PyPDF4 are not maintained and PyPDF2 is deprecated - `pypdf` is the way to go!

Three potential alternatives which are maintained:

- [`pymupdf`](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF): uses [mupdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MuPDF)
- [`pikepdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pikepdf/): Uses [qpdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPDF)
- [`pdfminer.six`](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six): A pure Python project. Don't confuse it with the unmaintained [`pdfminer`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/)

Comment: For the benefit of careless readers: note case: `pyPdf` has only one uppercase letter, while `PyPDF2` has 4.

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same error popping up after installing pypdf via pip and trying to import it in IPython (I'm using python 3.5.2):

```
In [5]: import pyPdf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a5780a4295f9> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyPdf

/home/mf/virtual_envs/pdfdataextract/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyPdf/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
      2 __all__ = ["pdf"]

ImportError: No module named 'pdf'
```

This was even after installing the `pdf` library using pip.

Luckily, there's a [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) library which works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, in your code you wrote:

```
from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
```

Instead of:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
```

Secondly use

```
pip3.x install pyPdf
```

instead of
`pip install pyPdf` if it will not work

Answer (score 7):

Use [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/).
I've been using it in Python 3 (v3.5.2 to be precise), and it works quite well.
Here's a simple command that you can use to install PyPDF2.

```
sudo -H pip3 install PyPDF2
```

For using it:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2023. (pypdf >= 3.16.2)**

I was looking to crop some pdf files and I found an answer [in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457207/cropping-pages-of-a-pdf-file) from 14 years ago, which pointed to what is now an updated link to the pypdf project (look wel, without capital letters).

I installed pypdf as in the project.

```py
pip install pypdf
```

And got the `ImportError`. In my python version is a `ModuleNotFoundVersion` because I used the script of 14 years ago, which imports `pyPdf` (with one Capital letter). So in summary my mistake was using `pyPdf`.

```py
# pyPdf worked 14 year ago. Now I have an error
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# pypdf is working well, so as the methods imported
from pypdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
```

These are the pitfalls of the history commented by @Martin Thoma in 2017.

Please, if you think this answer is valid, *consider clicking the "this answer is useful" button* so more people can see this answer rather than using `PyPDF2` or `PyPDF4` which are not very well maintained as `pypdf` at the time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I undeleted the PyPDF2 package from `/miniconda3` and re-installed in `/home`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I use pypdf2 , it work for me. 
pip install pypdf2. 
I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is a good comment but not an answer. please, read the rules of this community

Answer (score -1):

### I imported PDF library using python 3.8.5 as;

import PyPDF4

## or

from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader

---

it runs great.....

Answer (score -6):

Your import code should read:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
```